# ¿Porque mi código deja de funcionar cuando muevo los <select> dentro de un <td>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

No puedo usar el `jQuery` cuando coloco los `select` dentro de `<tabla>-<td>`

```js
$('.sel').each(function() {
    $(this).data('original', $(this).html());
});
$(document).on('change.sel', function() {
  $('.sel').each(function() {

    var valor = $(this).val();
    $(this).html($(this).data('original'));
    $(this).val(valor);
  });

  $('.sel').each(function() {

    $(this).siblings().find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
         <select class="sel">
           <option>Seleccion AA</option>
           <option value="1">a</option>
           <option value="2">b</option>
           <option value="3">c</option>
         </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="sel">
          <option>Seleccion BB</option>
          <option value="1">a</option>
          <option value="2">b</option>
          <option value="3">c</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option>Seleccion BB</option>
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
      </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Me explico mejor, los `<select>` deben estar en filas separadas uno debajo del otro, no en la misma celda, todo funciona sin la tabla, pero cuando agrego la tabla deja de funcionar.

Al seleccionar una opción de cualquier `<select>` ésta desaparece de los demás y ya me quedan solo dos opciones, automáticamente esa opción seleccionada se borra de los demás `<select>`; pero deja de funcionar cuando agrego los `<tr><td>` y demás, porque?

Comment: En realidad no los estás metiendo dentro de tags `td` si no directamente en los  `tr`, lo cual no es muy correcto. En cualquier caso deberías especificar qué comportamiento es el que tratas de conseguir con tu código para poder ver qué está fallando.

Comment: Si gracias ya está editada, me explico mejor, los <select> deben estar en filas separadas uno debajo del otro, no en la misma celda, todo funciona sin la tabla, pero cuando agrego la tabla deja de funcionar, me explico, al seleccionar una opcion de cualquier <select> ésta desaparece de los demás y ya me quedan solo dos opciones, automaticamente esa opcion seleccionada se borra de los demas <select>; pero deja de funcionar cuando agrego los <tr><td> y demás, porque? muchas gracias

Comment: Y cual es el funcionamiento que deseas observar?
Yo diria que esto es por causa de que los tres select tienen la clase sel
En lo personal yo utilizo el atributo onchange="metodoJS();" para saber cuando un select ha cambiado de seleccion

Comment: Es el mismo comportamiento, al seleccionar una opción de algún select, ésta opción desaparece de los demás select, es decir, no puedo volver a seleccionar la misma opción, todo funciona correctamente, hasta que uso la tabla-tr-td.. gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se da porque estas usando `$(this).siblings()`, es decir, estas buscando los `select` *hermanos* al que se esta controlando.

Al mover los `select` dentro de una tabla, estos ya no son hermanos.

### Solución:

Al momento de recorrer los `select` para remover las opciones seleccionadas, podrías usar `$('.sel').not(this)`, donde:

- `$('.sel')`, buscara todos los `select` (*incluyendo el que se esta controlando*), sin importar donde se encuentren, y
- [`.not(this)`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) para excluir el elemento que se esta controlando.

#### Demo:

```js
$('.sel').each(function() {
  $(this).data('original', $(this).html());
});
$(document).on('change.sel', function() {
  $('.sel').each(function() {

    var valor = $(this).val();
    $(this).html($(this).data('original'));
    $(this).val(valor);
  });

  $('.sel').each(function() {

    $('.sel').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="sel">
           <option>Seleccion AA</option>
           <option value="1">a</option>
           <option value="2">b</option>
           <option value="3">c</option>
         </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="sel">
          <option>Seleccion BB</option>
          <option value="1">a</option>
          <option value="2">b</option>
          <option value="3">c</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="sel">
        <option>Seleccion BB</option>
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactamente, eso es lo que queria, Muchas gracias @Marcos, saludos.

Comment: perfecto claro que si @Marcos, de nuevo muchas gracias.